# How can I check the running system from which device/partition it is from

Tags: boot, system-info

In Kubuntu 22.04 I have built in some hard disks drives and plugged in many USB drives. And some are mounted.

I need to ask the system from which device/partition it was booted from to get as detailed information as possible.

On the other hand  at boot time the boot menu shows very many entries but all with nearly the same short words, not able to associate these entries with the avalable devices.

How can I improve the deficiency?

Comment: What are you asking?  df will give you the root device, efibootmgr -v will give you the partition UUID of the entries, and sudo blkid will list the device with the part UUID (some EFI partition).

Comment: I like to label every partiiton, then this gives lots of detail. `lsblk-f` or with more detail: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid`

Comment: Thanks for response. efibootmgr and blkid are good tools. But these too do list more than 10 diveces. Yet they do not tell from which one running system is booted from

Comment: I have to go in more detatls.

Comment: continue: A) efibootmgr -v goes tward a solution. But my question was also for non-uefi systems. --- B) efibootmgr -v begins to tell what I need. In the first line it shows a boot-number from which it is bootet from. And then in lines below a clarification is given to each

Comment: continue: to each boot number, e.g. lines begin with "Boot0002*". Followed by a long sequece of Hex numbers, or in my trials somtimes by "Ubuntu Boot Manager" and numbers.  -- I need to know: 1. are these 27 lines the entries in the boot menu?  2. is the order in efibootmgr the same as in the Boot menu, so that one can make an assignmenr according to the order?  3. How can I use the long series of Hex numbers? They are not printed on the USB sticks for identification, I have no knowledge where and how to type it in, etc. thanks, regards, anton